# Sails JS - Limiting IP Address Range

Tags: heroku, ip-address, sails.js

Is there a way to limit a Sails.js app to a certain IP address range? Use case would be a corporate address range and any IP's outside of that range Sails would redirect to an error page. The app is running on heroku if that helps/alters the answer.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted...just wondering if it truly is best to add this to a global policy or if Sails has some other method of doing it.

Comment: First I never use heroku. I use aws and openshift mainly. I limit access by configure basic authentication & checking referrer in nginx. You may try. But it is not hard to configure nginx to limit [IP access](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/). this [heroku nginx-buildpack](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack) do have some healthy forks so you may check it out.